# Google Drive filename issues in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nautilus, google-drive, filename

This may not be an issue particular to Ubuntu 22.04 but rather simply the way Google Drive works, but I would like to find a workaround somehow. I am new to Ubuntu, so apologies if I cannot give more particular details or message errors.

I have linked my Google Drive files to my Ubuntu desktop and found that it is impossible to open them with certain programs. The issue seems to be coming from the fact that the filename on my Google Drive does not correspond with the human-readable name that I gave them.

Below is a screenshot of what happened when I attempted to edit a .tex file from TexMaker

[image]

As you can see the filename is really long, and although TexMaker can open the document, it cannot compile it into a PDF file. If I do a local copy then there are no issues, the document is opened and the filename displayed in Nautilus coincides with the one displayed by MikTex. This error extends to other programs, such as Xournal which is not able to open PDF files on my Google Drive.

I like to work directly on Google Drive so that all my edits are immediately synchronised, so I would greatly appreciate it if someone can help me find a way to work with and edit these files without having to first do a local copy and then reuploading them one by one.

Comment: @Nmath the filenames are as short as "file.tex" nothing too crazy - what is going on is that the filenames Google Drive uses do not correspond with the filenames that I gave. It looks like Google is using some sort of hash for the filenames

Comment: Oh I see. Hmm... The only thing I would suggest is to look and see if there are any reported bugs with filename lengths in TexMaker, especially if this is the only software that is giving you an issue. In the meantime I can't really think of a solution except to work with the files locally.